# Change default desktop manager

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, awesome

I'm kind of new into Linux world.

I'm using a Debian distro. I want to switch the default desktop manager into Awesome, and I want to boot straight to the command line, and from there start Awesome. 
How can I do that?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to change what's started in the default [runlevel](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel).  You can find that with `runlevel`; it's probably 2 (you'll see `N 2` -- in any case it's the last number).

Assuming it's 2, now `ls /etc/rc2.d` (or rc3.d, etc.).  Everything in there is a symlink with a prefix `S[N]` or `K[N]` where N is a number between 1 and 99.  Somewhere in that list you'll see (most likely) `S[N]gdm`, or possibly `S[N]lightdm` or `S[N]xdm`.  Something ending in `dm` (for display manager).  Double check by reading the comments in the top of this file; there should be a `Short Description` including mention of "display manager".

When you are sure what it is (e.g., below assuming `gdm`):

```
update-rc.d gdm disable 2
update-rc.d gdm stop 50 2
```

The last command is optional; it just makes sure `gdm` is stopped if you happen to change runlevels from something else.  If you use it, you should now see `K50gdm` instead of `S[N]gdm` in `/etc/rc2.d`.  If not (i.e., you just used "disable"), you won't see any listing for `gdm` at all in that directory.

Reboot to make sure that worked.  You should end up at the command line.

To use awesome, create a file `$HOME/.xinit`:

```
#!/bin/sh

awesome
```

Make that executable (`chmod a+x .xinit`), and run `startx`.

Answer (score 0):

After having disabled gdm for the runlevel 2 [(additionnal informations here)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77292/disable-gnome-on-a-debian-install), the file that you have to create in your home directory (/home/your_username) is .xinitrc and not .xinit

```
#!/bin/sh
exec awesome
```

You can find a lot of informations on .xinitrc [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc).

Then the startx command will launch awesome Wm