# Debian / Boot to CLI / No KDE

Tags: debian, kde

I'm trying to get Debian Jessie to boot to CLI, to allow me to start KDE manually.

I've tried:

```
sudo update-rc.d kdm disable
```

...but this results in:

```
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `kdm' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `kdm' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

Secondly, how do I start KDE manually.

---

I also reversed with the same first command (but enable) and then tried the following:

```
update-rc.d -f kdm remove
update-rc.d kdm stop 20 2 3 4 5 .
```

....which resulted in:

```
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: start runlevel arguments (none) do not match kdm Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning: stop runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match kdm Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
```

But the system still boots into KDE login prompt.

Comment: Does Debian still have `/etc/inittab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question on a number of forums, it seems that there may be a number of ways to A: Force booting to console and B: start KDE once at the console.
I've however found, that only the following works, for me.

```
update-rc.d kdm disable
reboot
```

My system now boots to CLI.  I login and

```
service kdm start
```

The KDE login screen (KDM) starts, allowing me to login to KDE.

Answer (score 3):

First, the "insserv: warning" ... is just that, warnings. The command has still succeeded and would have disabled kdm from starting automatically.

However, in order to disable the display manager, you could instead edit
/etc/X11/default-display-manager and make sure the file exists but is empty.

Reboot and you should get to the console.

If you need to re-enable a display manager, you should use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-window-manager
```

Your second question, "how do i start kde manually?":

the command is `startkde`

you may also reconfigure X11 to start kde by default, and then "startx" would bring up kde for you.

Here is a related question: [How to boot Debian into text mode without using GUI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15527/how-to-boot-debian-into-text-mode-without-using-gui)

Comment: Thanks, I've had bits of similar assistance on G+,. but the whole story. This seems far more coherent, will check out later and Tick when (and if) it works, which I'm sure it will.

Comment: I get [$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.]