# debian installation on lenovo p1

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation

i have a brand-new lenovo p1 workstation and i'm unable to install linux on it. it's even not possible to start debian 9 (or 10 alpha), ubuntu or mint live cd. it just stops without an error while booting.
it is possible to install debian 10 on it but it stops during boot with the attached output. i have no idea why.

[image]

Comment: There might be a graphics/driver issue. Have you tried [booting without a gui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15527/how-to-boot-debian-into-text-mode-without-using-gui)? You are probably using GRUB, so you should press `e` after selecting a boot option and then add `single` to the cmdline and maybe remove `quiet`. This will not fix your problem, but should enable you to boot (as you said, you were able to install debain, you should be able to boot it without graphics as well) and perhaps install the correct drivers.

Comment: google :  lenovo p1  install linux   ....  I am seeing solutions

Comment: thanks for your answer. i already googled it but without success. that's why i posted here. I also thought that it's graphics/driver issue but during investigation i think it's based on SGX, Thunderbold or CPU Power Management. I disabled all of this features in BIOS Setup without success. after your input i will try to install without gui and let you know. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

now i found first part of the soltution in a discussion in another forum. after a bios upgrade i'm able to install & run debian.
the bios version which works for me is:

```
v1.10  20 Sep 2018

Version 1.10
 UEFI: 1.10 / ECP: 1.07
 (Fix) Fixed an issue where the memory frequency was unexpected setting
 with Intel Core i5 and Xeon processor.
```

you can download it here:
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/at/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p1-type-20md-20me/downloads/ds504958

and you had to disable in bios:

```
Intel SpeedStep Technology
CPU Power Management
8254 Timer Clock Gating
```

Comment: Do you have link to that _another forum_? I am curious about the reasoning behind what to disable and why.