# How can I automatically start from the terminal in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux

I'd like to know what I can do to **start my Kali from the terminal and not from the graphic environment**. I mean, my computer is very slow and the only thing I want is the terminal (but including all the tools from the Kali Linux), so I think my best option is only use the terminal mode of Linux, but I don't know how.

**I want to set an option to automatically start my Kali Linux in the terminal mode**.

If anyone knows, can you also tell me how I can go from the terminal mode to the graphic mode? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is not working? Please edit your post to include these details. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry. I know it's kind of a "rule" to include that kind of details... but i'm new in linux. I haven't tried anything because there is no information (or i don't know how to search it).

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15527/how-to-boot-debian-into-text-mode-without-using-gui) thread may help with your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to boot Debian into text mode without using GUI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15527/how-to-boot-debian-into-text-mode-without-using-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome and KDE are heavy resources and consumes more **memory** that it appears.

You have to switch fom the **graphical-target** to  **multi-user.target** that means changing the current system **RUN Level** ; to do so :

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To check the current Run Level  :

```
sudo systemctl get-default
```

Obviously, these commands are available with a recent Kali versions based on **Systemd** instead of **SysV**.